# Redirecting page to a Success page if server validation is positive

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with an action that is linked to the same PHP page contact.php. I have all the server side validation inside the form and it's all fine. It redirects the user to the same page with error messages echoed if needed while making the form STICKY (that is the main point of using the same page for errors).

What I would like is for there to be a success page redirect if the form was okay. I've read other posts on how to implement this, but I don't quite understand how to implement it in my code.

```
<?php
$fullname = $email = $reason = $contactbox = '';
$fullnameerr = $emailerr = $reasonerr = $contactboxerr = '';

if(data_post('submit')){
  if(empty(data_post('firstname'))){
    $fullnameerr = "Please enter a valid name";
  }

  else {
    $fullname = clean_data(data_post('firstname'));
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z '']*$/", $fullname)){
      $fullnameerr = "Please enter only alphabetical characters and white spaces";
    }
  }

  if(empty(data_post('email'))){
    $emailerr = "Please enter a valid e-mail";
  }
  else {
    $email = clean_data(data_post('email'));
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $emailerr = "Please enter a correct e-mail format (ex 'joe@cornell.edu')";
    }
  }

  if(empty(data_post('reason'))){
  $reasonerr = "Please select a reason for contact";
}
  else{
    $reason = clean_data(data_post('reason'));
  }

  if(empty(data_post('contacttext'))){
    $contactboxerr = "Please elaborate on your reason"; 
  }
  else{
    $contactbox = clean_data(data_post('contacttext'));
    if(!preg_match("/^[\w\S\s]*$/", $contactbox )){
      $contactboxerr = "Please enter only valid characters you would use in writing (ex 'abcABC123')";
    }

    if(strlen($contactbox) > 2000){
      $contactboxerr = "Please enter a response with with a max of 2000 characters.";
    }
  }
}

function clean_data($field){
  $field = trim($field);
  $field = stripslashes($field);
  return $field;
}

function data_post($param){
  if (isset($_POST[$param])){
    return $_POST[$param];
  }
  else{
    return '';
  }
}
?>
```

With this being the code for the form:

```
<div class="sidesection" id="survey">
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" novalidate>
<span class="required_asterick">* Is Required</span>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Contact Us</legend>
  <span class="required_asterick">* </span><label>Name:</label><span class="help" data-tooltip="Please enter a valid name (Ex. 'John Doe')"></span><br />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z '']+" maxlength="25" title="Enter only characters from (a-z) and (A-Z)" value="<?php echo "$fullname";?>"><span class="errormessage"><?php echo "$fullnameerr";?></span><br /><br />

  <span class="required_asterick">* </span><label>Email:</label><span class="help" data-tooltip="Please enter a valid email with a max of 50 characters. (Ex. 'xxx@yyy.com')"></span><br />
  <input type="email" name="email" required maxlength="50" value="<?php echo "$email";?>">
  <span class="errormessage"><?php echo "$emailerr"; ?></span><br /><br />

  <span class="required_asterick">* </span><label>Reason For Contact:</label>
  <select name="reason" required>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="concern">Concern</option>
    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
  </select><span class="help" data-tooltip="Choose a topic for which you are contacting us so we can process your request faster. General is for any broad topics not listed. Concern is for any pressing matter you may have about the Ithaca Apple Harvest Festival. Feedback is for any suggestions or opinions you wish to share with us about our festivals. "></span><span class="errormessage"><?php echo "$reasonerr";?></span><br /> <br />

  <span class="required_asterick">* </span><label>What Would You Like To Tell Us?</label><span class="help" data-tooltip="Use this section to write what you are contacting us for."></span><br />
  <textarea name="contacttext" rows="7" cols="60" required><?php echo "$contactbox";?></textarea><span class="errormessage"><?php echo "$contactboxerr"; ?></span><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can see I made the form sticky by adding echoes to errors, so I want to keep that if there are errors. However if it is successful, redirect to a success page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if you have no errors (i.e. your error variables are empty) and use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php)

```
$fullname = $email = $reason = $contactbox = '';
$fullnameerr = $emailerr = $reasonerr = $contactboxerr = '';

if(data_post('submit')){

    // your validations go here
    // ......

    if (empty($fullnameerr) && empty($emailerr) && empty($reasonerr) && empty($contactboxerr)) {
         header('Location: success.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow! I am such an idiot. Thank you for pointing that out for me, I can't believe I overlooked setting error variables to empty. I knew of the header('Location:') method but never knew how to implement it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a control to check whether the validation passed or failed. As a suggestion user a boolean variable to indicate it:

```
if(data_post('submit')){

    $valid=true;
    if(empty(data_post('firstname'))){
        $fullnameerr = "Please enter a valid name";
        $valid=false;
    }
    if(empty(data_post('email'))){
        $emailerr = "Please enter a valid e-mail";
        $valid=false;
    }

    //other validations
    if($valid){
         //validation passed
         header('Location: destination.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Deimoks answer, you may need to call `exit();` after calling the header() function. If you have any code after the header redirection, it could still be executed even you requested a redirection. `exit()` prevents that.  Also, if you get the "headers already sent" error, look into [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).